# Wrong value read from DataFrame while iterrows()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, dataframe

I have build a dataframe that represents a hierarchy. Now I am trying to go through this data frame iteratively (iteration although not good but I think only this is applicable to my case) changing values of the data frame and deleting rows according to my program calculations.

For the first two iterations, the program reads the data frame rows correctly. However in third iteration (always), it is reading old values I think.

In case, I have not been able to make it clear enough, here is the ipython notebook: [Ipython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/s0j0urn/7a82dddc28323947071b)

Initial Dataframe :

```
        c1   c2  c3    c4
   19   21   20  14  0.718004
   18   20   21  14  0.749271
   17   19   18  17  0.724873
   16   18   19  17  0.647143
   15   17   16  11  0.348749
   14   16   17  11  0.847751
   13   15   14   9  0.597245
   12   14   15   9  0.596115
   11   13   12   8  0.549009
   10   12   13   8  0.810719
    9    11   10   7  0.328420
    8    10   11   7  0.859816
    7     9    8   6  0.449287
    6     8    9   6  0.724799
    5     7    6   4  0.320076
    4     6    7   4  0.306391
    3     5    4   2  0.809620
    2     4    5   2  0.450804
    1     3    2   1  0.771699
    0     2    3   1  0.118202
```

Problematic code:

```
computed_dataframe.sort_values(['c1'], ascending=0, inplace = True)
for index, row in computed_dataframe.iterrows():
    print computed_dataframe
    print row['c3']
    if row['c3'] == 1:
        break
    select_final(row['c3'])
    print computed_dataframe
```

Function definition

```
def select_final(check_label): 
.....
.....
    parent_frame = computed_dataframe[computed_dataframe['c1'] == check_label]

    parent_score = get_parent_row_frame.iloc[0]['c4']
    if avg > parent_score:
        for i in child_index:
           computed_dataframe.loc[i,'c2'] = parent_row_frame.iloc[0]['c3']
     computed_dataframe = computed_dataframe[computed_dataframe.c1 != parent_frame.iloc[0]['c1']]
    elif avg <= parent_score:
     computed_dataframe = computed_dataframe[computed_dataframe.c3 != check_label]

return
```

Iteration 1: row['c3'] pointed to 14

Resulting frame from 1st iteration:

```
        c1   c2  c3    c4
   19   21   20  9  0.718004
   18   20   21  9  0.749271
   17   19   18  17  0.724873
   16   18   19  17  0.647143
   15   17   16  11  0.348749
   14   16   17  11  0.847751
   13   15   14   9  0.597245
   # Deleted with c1 = 14 
   11   13   12   8  0.549009
   10   12   13   8  0.810719
   ......
   ......
```

Iteration 2: Read index 18. row['c3'] pointed to 9

Resulting frame from 2nd iteration:

```
        c1   c2  c3    c4
   19   21   20  6  0.718004
   18   20   21  6  0.749271
   17   19   18  17  0.724873
   16   18   19  17  0.647143
   15   17   16  11  0.348749
   .....
   # Deleted row with c1 = 9 
   .........
```

Iteration 3: Read index 17. row['c3'] pointed to 17

Resulting frame from 3rd iteration:

```
        c1   c2  c3    c4
   19   21   20  6  0.718004
   18   20   21  6  0.749271
   17   19   18  11  0.724873
   16   18   19  11  0.647143
   #Deleted row with c1 17
   14   16   17  11  0.8477
   .....
   ..... 
   .........
```

Iteration 4: **Read index 16. row['c3'] points to 11.**

**However, the program is still reading row['c3'] as 17 somehow** and then I run into the error while executing the function because it doesn't find any match in c1 corresponding to 17 and, therefore, my computations result in division by zero error. I am unable to understand from where it is still reading c3 as 17. The dataframe printed shows the updated value as 11 at that index.

Will someone please help me out in resolving this error and from where it is popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was updating the same dataframe I was iterating over.